# Are Pokemon's moving or standing where they spawned in map-mode?

Tags: pokemon-go

1. In the map-mode, Pokemons are disappearing after a while or after restarting the app.

Are they moving or is it just that their duration is ending?

2. Also, while I am tracking them according to Nearby menu, sometimes its looks like a Pokemon is getting further away and disappearing. Then I am asking again to myself;

Are they moving or they are standing where they are but me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a Pokemon spawns in, it does not move. It remains in the same spot for 15 minutes, then despawns.
A Pokemon may also disappear if it flees while you are trying to capture it. Each Pokemon has a certain flee chance.

Comment: Is that 15-mins-period tested?

Comment: I've checked it with an external program.

Comment: You sure that holds up for all Pokémon, and not just the specific case you checked? I can't be certain, but I could swear I've had Pokémon appear and disappear in a less-than-15-minute timeframe while standing perfectly still.

Comment: It is a 15 minute window. If you just entered a new area, they were probably already spawned.

Answer (score 3):

Pokémon stand still where they spawn until their timer is up.

It is also worth noting that the "nearby" menu is currently very broken. Not only does it only show "3 feet" distance, but Pokémon can also get stuck there. As in, they can stay on your nearby list, while they have already despawned. Restarting the game helps.
As for why you might see Pokémon moving further away on the list, new Pokémon can spawn closer than the Pokémon you are tracking, or you yourself can actually be moving in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Pokemon stand still in this game, if they have disappeared then their timer has ended. They stand where they spawn and disappear when their timer ends.